# Is there a prayer to rebuke storms at sea?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, saint, prayer-book

My mom comes from a family of fishermen and ship captains, the vast majority of all men in her city are still doing of those professions, I live in Lebanon, middle east.

She told me more than once that her grandpa used to rebuke or let waterspout or sea tornadoes disappear by prayer to a saint some special prayer, maybe saint George. The grandpa is Catholic Maronite, which is in essence just Catholic.

I googled it, I got nothing, I just want to know if such prayers exist in Christianity and if people used to say them historically, I found few videos like this:

[Man Rebukes Tornado in the Name of Jesus Christ (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_h8W2yhbjY)

In fact if you google something like "Prayers Rebukes a Tornado" you'll see plenty of videos, most of them are just

'In the name of Jesus I command you to go'

But that's not what my question is about, nor whether these videos are fake or not. My question is this:

Is there a special prayer that only few people know, that people used to pray to a saint in order to rebuke a tornado or a waterspout? My mom is pretty certain of it, all her family are certain too, it's just that, her grandpa never told the prayer to anyone and passed away.

Comment: While I think this is a pretty fascinating question, it might be a bit like all the [Amish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amish) questions we don't have answers for. What Church would your Grandfather have grown up around to learn such a prayer? FWIW, I did find a "prayer in time of calamity" in the [Raccolata](http://www.saintsbooks.net/books/The%20Raccolta%20-%201910.pdf)

Comment: @PeterTurner Thanks for the document, I'll read it now. The grandpa is Catholic Maronite, which is in essence just Catholic

Comment: I'm not sure saying a prayer that saves you from a tornado but destroys your neighbor's homes was actually the work of God.  I'm guessing a Christian who emulates Christ would take the suffering so others might be spared, or at the very least, prevent the tornado from doing any harm to anyone, even unbelievers.  I'm guessing, some prayers went unanswered as the tornado destroyed homes.   Pray for the victims of the Tornado, then rush out your door and help them, that is how prayer works.

Comment: @Marc regarding the video, it was just an example I found on youtube. The prayer that my mother grandpa used to say allegedly made waterspouts disappear. In my country, tornadoes never happen, but waterspouts or sea tornadoes  sometimes happen and that prayer allegedly made them disappear, rather than just saving one person.

Comment: I now of a Lebanese family in our Parish and will ask them when I see them next for additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particular prayer that your grandfather once prayed to calm storms at sea will be rather hard to pinpoint as there are many [saints invoked against storms](http://catholicsaints.info/patrons-against-storms/) and this list is not a complete one. Both St. Michael the Archangel and St. Nicholas of Myra are traditionally [invoked against storms at sea](http://catholicsaints.info/patrons-against-storms-at-sea/). St. Peter is one of the [patron saint of fishermen](http://catholicsaints.info/patrons-of-fishermen/). As you see there is a large list in play and we may never know for sure.

I will give here three hopeful possibilities, but before going into detail I would like to mention the Scriptures tell us that Our Lord (Matthew 8:24-28) and the Prophet Jonah (Jonah 1:11-12) both calmed storms at sea and could be invoked as the need presents. The Prophet Jonah is honoured on September 21 in the Roman Martyrology.

The most popular saint invoked against storms is St. Scholastica (February 10). In Malta, there is a unique feast in St. Paul the Apostle's honour known as the [Shipwreck of St. Paul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5Pn8zxTWp8) (***Naufragium S. Pauli***), which is also held on the 10th of February. How St. Scholastica became invoked against storms can be found [here](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/calendar/day.cfm?date=2014-02-10). In times of real necessity the short prayers are the easiest to recite.

**St. Scholastica and St. Paul the Apostle, pray for us.**

My second suggestion is the traditional prayer to repel dangerous storms taken from the missal of 1962. I personally use these sort of prayers in my own private devotional life accompanied with St. Scholastica.

> When a major storm is headed your way, you should prepare as much as you can. But you should also pray.
>
> Prayer is powerful, and it can change history. No, we don’t always get what we prayed for. But God always hears us – and sometimes he does grant us what we pray for.
>
> These prayers, titled “Ad Repellendas Tempestates” (“To Repel Storms”), are meant to be used in the extraordinary form of the Mass at their respective parts (and some people are using them!). But feel free to use them as inspiration for your own personal prayer.
>
> Here’s the original Latin:
>
> **A domo tua, quǽsumus, Dómine, spiritales nequítiæ, repellantur: et aërearum discédat malígnitas tempestatum. Per Dóminum.**
>
> And here’s an English translation:
>
> We beseech Thee, O Lord, that all wickedness being driven away from Thy house, the fury of the raging tempest may pass away. Through our Lord.
>
> [The Traditional Catholic Mass Prayers to Repel Dangerous Storms](https://churchpop.com/2017/09/08/the-traditional-catholic-mass-prayers-to-repel-dangerous-storms/)

My last suggestion is a prayer to St. Medard.

> [Prayer against tornadoes?](https://www.archbalt.org/prayer-against-tornadoes-are-the-rich-evil/)
>
> I am not aware of any specific prayer against tornadoes, but I do know that St. Medard is traditionally regarded as the patron saint against bad weather. He was a bishop in France during the first half of the sixth century.
>
> Legend has it that when he was a child, he was once sheltered from a violent rainstorm by an eagle that hovered over his head. That is how he is commonly depicted in art, and Christians have long invoked his aid in stormy weather.
>
> The prayer that is said admits of different versions but generally goes something like this:
>
> **“Lord Jesus, though the intercession of St. Medard, be with me during the storms of my life and the storms of nature. Protect the victims of hurricanes, tornadoes, earthquakes and other natural disasters. Send in helpers and multiply the supplies that are needed for their aid. You calmed the storm on the Sea of Galilee; deliver us now from the storms that rage around us. Amen.”**

Answer (score 1):

My dad told me stories of my grandpa and my great grandpa, who knew a certain prayer for "cutting a storm in half" to avert storms while they were fishing.  My great grandpa was from Yugoslavia and settled in Buras, Louisiana. They were oyster fishermen and would be working along the coast of Louisiana during storms.  My dad told me they would hold up a knife to the sky and say a special prayer, to cut the storm in half.  My dad was told that the prayer can only be taught on the feast day of St. John the Baptist.  There are other prayers families used to pray: for someone to stop bleeding and for someone who has severe pain.  I was told these prayers can only be taught on St. John the Baptist's feast day: 24 June.  I have a very old  handwritten copy of a few of these prayers, but the handwriting is very hard to read.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Answer (score -1):

My grandfather told me a very similar story the other day. He lived in Sicily as a Shepard and told us that sailors would come to the main land during a storm and say a special prayer and use a black handled knife to cut the storm in half. Only a few knew the prayer and he was never taught it. I found it strange that such a power prayer was never taught to him. We live in Canada now as farmers and according to him a fellow farmer who also lived in Sicily knew the prayer but wouldn’t share it with him even going as far as saying he wouldn’t even teach his sons. He also mentioned that the prayer could only be taught to someone 3 times. If anyone knows of the prayer I’d like to be taught as it could be useful as I’m a farmer as well. Not to mention all the questions I have about said prayer and it’s secrecy.